# How can I access the iTunes DB in VB6?

Tags: database, vb6, io, itunes, ipod

I am trying to rewrite a closed-source program called Pod Player (written in VB6). To do anything, I need to be able to access the iPod's DB and load it into a series of ListBox controls. Things I need to access is: any playlists and what they contain, the iPod's name, track numbers, song titles, genres, artists, albums, path to the songs, their rating, UIN, file size, length and preferably album artwork. I also need to be able to change rating information if needed. So how can I interact (read/write) with the iPod's DB in VB6?

Or is it possible to write a DLL or OCX in another language that can do this and be called/used by the VB6 program?

I should also mention that Pod Player uses some or most of SharePod's code (before SP went .NET).

I found a [database parser on Planet Source Code](http://www.planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=62429&lngWId=1) and tried out the demo form included as well as an implementation of it in my Pod Player rewrite, but (according to the demo form) it only reads 76% of the database before dropping out due to a playlist-related problem. I tested it on an iNano 4 and an iShuffle 4 and both are completely compatible with Pod Player. How can I get it (parser is in iPod.bas) to work correctly?

Comment: I highly doubt that Apple publish their database formats. You can try and reverse engineer it but expect it to change at any time.

Comment: The iPod database seems to have stayed the same since the original iPod because Pod Player was able to access pretty much any disk-mode iPod (excluding iTouch) in existence except iPod Nano 6 (which probably uses some weird variant of the DB).

Comment: According to Jack from PSC, "all iPod databases (or at least the iTunesDB file) are constructed the same". Not sure if this applies to the iNano 6, though.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this page: http://homepage.ntlworld.com/simon.mason20/ipod_tunes_spec.htm

It contains details of the iTunes database format